# Android - .setText() and invalidate() don't work in just one class

Tags: java, android

So here's my code:

```
package org.skaza.pocketamati.CalculatorActivities;

import android.content.Context;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.inputmethod.InputMethodManager;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import org.skaza.pocketamati.R;

public class SizeViolinActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_size_violin);
    setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.sizeViolin));

}

String violinSize = "NaN";
double bodyLength = 0;
int indicator = 0;

public void Compute(View v) {
    InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
    inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(), InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);

    EditText bodyLengthText = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.sizeViolinInput);

    if (bodyLengthText
            .getText()
            .toString()
            .matches("\\d+(\\.\\d*)?|\\.\\d+")) {
        bodyLength = Double.parseDouble(bodyLengthText
                .getText()
                .toString());
    } else {
        Context context = getApplicationContext();
        CharSequence text = "Incorrect value";
        int length = Toast.LENGTH_SHORT;
        Toast error = Toast.makeText(context, text, length);
        error.show();
    }

    if (bodyLength >= 280 && bodyLength < 300) {indicator = 1;}
    if (bodyLength >= 300 && bodyLength < 320) {indicator = 2;}
    if (bodyLength >= 320 && bodyLength <= 340){indicator = 3;}
    if (bodyLength >= 350 && bodyLength <= 360){indicator = 4;}

    switch (indicator){
        case 1: violinSize = "1/4"; break;
        case 2: violinSize = "1/2"; break;
        case 3: violinSize = "3/4"; break;
        case 4: violinSize = "4/4"; break;
        default: break;}
    }

    TextView sizeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sizeView);
    sizeTextView.setText(violinSize);
    sizeTextView.invalidate();

}
```

The only two lines that don't seem to work in the entire app are

```
    sizeTextView.setText(violinSize);
    sizeTextView.invalidate();
```

Those two work in other parts of my application but do not here. I had to invalidate cache and restart because all my symbols were like this. Now I'm stuck with those two and am unable to find a solution for it on the internet.

Comment: by 'those two' I mean .setText() and invalidate()

Comment: Do you get a stacktrace or do you not see anything changing?

Comment: I'm not sure if I'm answering you right but I'm not even compiling or building it since it's not able to resolve my symbol

Comment: I see the problem, added an answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

fisrt you must initiate variables inside methods not in main class definition:

```
  TextView sizeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sizeView);
```

so set `sizeTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.sizeView);` inside onCreate method, then do your next calls also inside a method

Comment: Hey could you please look at: https://github.com/Sjalistra/PocketAmati/blob/master/app/src/main/java/org/skaza/pocketamati/CalculatorActivities/ScaleLengthActivity.java this one works perfectly fine and I basically copied off it. Also, when I do what you suggest it just simply doesn't work still

Comment: @Sjalistra the git code inserted setText() an invalidate() inside compute method but you did outside of that method and in main class definition

Comment: just move your calls into a method as i said and your problem will be reolved,

Answer (score 0):

From where Compute is called? IF it is called from thread or something like this - you need to use setText on UI thread.

Comment: It's an on click method

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not with setting the text, in your switch right on top of it, you have a closing bracket that should not be there. That's preventing you from building.

```
    switch (indicator){
        case 1: violinSize = "1/4"; break;
        case 2: violinSize = "1/2"; break;
        case 3: violinSize = "3/4"; break;
        case 4: violinSize = "4/4"; break;
        default: break;} // <- this '}' right here can be removed
    }
```

If you remove that one, it compiles.

BTW, in below line, you can also remove `this` because `INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE` is defined static

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager) getSystemService(this.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE);
```

Comment: It's actually because the set text and invalidate aren't inside the compute method but yeah it's a bracket problem